# can you show screen_name of users who have liked an entry?

Tags: query, query-module, channel-ratings

Channel Ratings: 4.0.4, EE: 2.7.3

I am using the channel ratings "Like" function, so the logged in users can "Like" certain products. I want to be able to display who has liked an entry. I am using this bit of code to display the "like_author_id" which happens to be the same as the "member_id"

```
{exp:query 
   sql="SELECT * 
   FROM exp_channel_ratings_likes
   WHERE entry_id = '{entry_id}'
   AND liked > '0'
"}
   {if like_author_id != "0"}
      <a href="{path='/likes/{like_author_id}'}">{like_author_id}</a>,
   {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

I am wondering how I can display the screen_name of the author who liked the entry.

ps. I tried to tag channel-ratings, but I couldn't with under 150 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with Channel Ratings, but you should be able to do what you're looking for with the query.

Try this:

```
{exp:query 
   sql="SELECT exp_channel_ratings.*, exp_members.screen_name as like_screen_name 
   FROM exp_channel_ratings_likes, exp_members
   WHERE entry_id = '{entry_id}' and exp_channel_ratings.like_author_id = exp_members.member_id
   AND liked > '0'"}
       {if like_author_id != "0"}
          <a href="{path='/likes/{like_author_id}'}">{like_screen_name}</a>,
       {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

Note: You may want to change that `exp_channel_ratings.*` to use the specific fields you want to query, reducing the number of fields pulled back in your query. Could help with performance.

Comment: Awesome thanks Jeremy, I've been trying a few things along this line, but it still pulls in the screen_name associated with the entry, and not the "like". I'll try playing around with this code and let you know if it works!

Comment: I've just updated the query to alias the screen_name field to {like_screen_name}. It may have been conflicting with the outer channel entries tag.

Comment: "as like_screen_name" did it! You're my hero Jeremy